# Java RDP login protocol

Tags: java, windows, terminal, desktop

I wanted to make a login program for remote desktop using windows terminal. I found tho that the amount of packets I have to recreate is ridiculous. Is there any pre-written code for just the login sequence?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find an free-standing Java library for doing this kind of thing, but there are Java clients available.  Take a look at the Java RDP client listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software) and see if you can reuse some of their code.